Can I play an audio file in the background using a service-worker.js file?
Here is what I've tried:
// service-worker.js
self.addEventListener('install', function (event) {
    console.log('Service Worker: Installed');
    event.waitUntil(self.skipWaiting());
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function (event) {
    console.log('Service Worker: Activated');
    event.waitUntil(self.clients.claim());
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
    // Handle fetch events if needed
    // console.log('Fetch event:', event.request.url);
});

let audioContext;
let audioBuffer;
let source;

self.addEventListener('message', async (event) => {
    console.log('Service Worker: Received message:', event.data);

    if (event.data.action === 'play') {
        const url = event.data.url;
        console.log('Play action received for URL:', url);

        if (!audioContext) {
            audioContext = new AudioContext();
        }

        const response = await fetch(url);
        const arrayBuffer = await response.arrayBuffer();
        audioBuffer = await audioContext.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer);

        source = audioContext.createBufferSource();
        source.buffer = audioBuffer;
        source.connect(audioContext.destination);
        source.start(0);
        console.log('Audio started playing.');
    }

    if (event.data.action === 'stop') {
        if (source) {
            source.stop();
            console.log('Audio stopped.');
        }
    }
});




Here is my Layout.svelte in ./components:
<script>
    import GlobalNavBar from './GlobalNavBar.svelte';
    import NavBar from './NavBar.svelte';
    import Sidebar from './Sidebar.svelte';
    import MetaTags from './MetaTags.svelte';
    import Footer from './Footer.svelte';
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';

    export let isLoggedIn, unverifiedUser, isAdmin;
    let hasServiceWorker = false;
    let audioUrl = '/086-Jailbreak.mp3';

    function playAudio() {
        console.log('play clicked');
        if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
            console.log('controller1');

            navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage({ action: 'play', url: audioUrl });
            console.log('Play message sent to Service Worker.');
        }
    }

    function stopAudio() {
        console.log('stop clicked');
        if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
            console.log('controller2');
            navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage({ action: 'stop' });
            console.log('Stop message sent to Service Worker.');
        }
    }

    onMount(async () => {
        if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
            navigator.serviceWorker
                .register('/service-worker.js')
                .then(function (registration) {
                    console.log('Service Worker registered with scope:', registration.scope);
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.error('Service Worker registration failed:', error);
                });

            navigator.serviceWorker.ready
                .then(function (registration) {
                    console.log('A service worker is active:', registration.active);
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.error('Service Worker ready failed:', error);
                });

            navigator.serviceWorker.ready
                .then(function (registration) {
                    console.log('Service Worker is ready:', registration.active);
                    if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
                        console.log('A service worker is controlling this page.');
                    } else {
                        console.log('No service worker is controlling this page.');
                    }
                })
                .catch(console.error);
        }
    });
</script>

<MetaTags />

<GlobalNavBar {isLoggedIn} {unverifiedUser} {isAdmin} />
<main>
    <Sidebar {isLoggedIn} {unverifiedUser} />

    <div class="content">
        {#if isLoggedIn}
            <NavBar {isLoggedIn} {isAdmin} />
        {/if}
        <h1>Persistent Media Player</h1>
        <button on:click|preventDefault={playAudio}>Play</button>
        <button on:click|preventDefault={stopAudio}>Stop</button>
        <slot />
    </div>
</main>

<style>
    .content {
        padding: 1.2rem 2.4rem;
    }
</style>

it tries to load a local mp3 file from /<name>.mp3 the mp3 plays fine int he browser directly but I can't seem to get service worker to get a response from the postMessage call.
This is not being logged in the console:
    console.log('Service Worker: Received message:', event.data);

This question is similar to: Play a sound from a Service Worker. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

that has no answer other than it was removed from the spec.

If it's not in the spec you probably can't do this (which is what I would have expected).

bummer. thanks for the clarification.
